# How do Baldur's Gate and Baldur's Gate 2's "rolling" for stats actually get generated?

Tags: ability-scores, adnd-2e

When I have played BG1 & BG2, a big part of the character creation is rolling (and rerolling) for stats. This rolling for stats is subjected to racial minimums and maximums (and class minimums iirc).

The result of the rolling mechanism is a number of points allocated to specific scores, but you can reassign them in a simple 1-1 fashion between stats, subject to the relevant minimums and maximums.

How, though, are the stats generated? Is it in line with AD&D 2nd edition rules? Or have they come up with their own rolling mechanism for the game, and if so what is that rolling mechanism?

The reason behind the question is that I am interested in developing a similar stats generation system for D&D 5e tabletop games I run, but wanted to get a baseline for the "canonicity" of this generation system in relation to AD&D 2e rules first.

Comment: @Someone_Evil The question is about the conflux of a specific crpg ostensibly created using the rules of a specific version of a  ttrpg game, and I'm asking does the system for rolling stats in the crpg follow the rules for that ttrpg, or does it use an alternative system. We have people here with expertise in the ttrpg, so I would (possibly naively) expect it to be on topic here.

Comment: IMO the question could be on topic in both places, as it is about a computer game but is also about the mechanics of a roleplaying game.

Comment: We also have questions about how to program a popular dice-simulation web application which honestly are of similarly dubious required-expertise relative to the stack's subject matter, but nonetheless are accepted as relevant because of the close relationship to what we do care about. Which is to say that just because a question involves math, or programming, or a videogame, it isn't automatically off-topic for rpg.se.

Comment: @Carcer I've asked a question on the meta about it: [Are all questions that are even tangentially related to Computer Based RPGs or computer games off topic for this stack?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/are-all-questions-that-are-even-tangentially-related-to-computer-based-rpgs-off)

Comment: By virtue of the question requiring knowledge on the rules of stat rolling in AD&D to properly answer, I think this is on-topic and am voting to re-open. The fact that someone might also need knowledge of a computer game is irrelevant for the purposes of being on-topic, though it may reduce the number of qualified respondents.

Comment: Is this question asking about the originally published versions of these to CRPGs or the remade "Enhanced Editions" that are currently available?  The EE versions of the games make some changes, such as removing the racial maximum level restrictions.  I do not know/remember how it was in the original versions but in the EE versions the sum of the 6 stats is never less than 75 to prevent having a main character who is too under-powered.

Comment: @krb the originals with the restrictions (I'm not familiar with the updates). Though if the only difference for stat generation is what you've mentioned then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @illustro I made an edit to the earlier comment.  when rolling a main character, have you ever seen it give less than 75 points for stats?

Comment: @krb Honestly can't remember, but the only versions I've played are the originals not the EE ones

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It's 3d6 with floors based on race/class

According to the [Baldur's Gate fandom wikia](https://baldursgate.fandom.com/wiki/Character_Generation) and my own recollection playing BG1 and BG2, the stat generation is implemented as a simple 3d6 roll plus racial modifiers for each attribute, which is the default "Method I" approach used in 2e AD&D - *but* with the notable exception that, since the BG character generation system has you choose race and class *before* ability scores are generated, the values generated are floored by the minimum attribute required by the character's race and/or class.

For instance, a Paladin must have a Charisma of 17, so if the rolled Charisma score is less than 17 it is automatically raised to 17. Similarly, Elves have a minimum dexterity of 7, so if the rolled Dexterity is worse than 7, the score is just set to 7 instead. [This fandom wikia page](https://baldursgate.fandom.com/wiki/Ability_Scores#In_Character_Generation) includes a table of all the minimum/maximum ability score limits for the various races and classes. These class requirements and racial minimums are taken straight from the 2e PHB, but in normal 2e character generation they apply *after* ability scores are generated, limiting which race and class you can choose.

These adjustments have the effect of skewing the generated results somewhat better than you would expect from rolling 3d6 down the line, to greater or lesser extent depending on exactly which combination of race and class(es) were chosen. The least advantaged combinations are human fighters, clerics, mages or thieves, since humans rock a default minimum 3 in each stat and those classes each require only one stat at 9 or better.

The mechanic allowing you to then reassign "points" in different statistics on one-to-one basis cannot be found in the 2e PHB, which provides several different alternative methods for generating ability scores besides standard 3d6 in order, but all of them involve allocating a given roll (or even individually rolled dice!) to a specific score. However, the *Player's Option - Skills & Powers* book does include some more ability score generation methods, a couple of which require the player to simply assign points to ability scores one-for-one - though none of them involve rolling the scores in the "normal" way and then adjusting. *Skills & Powers* predates Baldur's Gate by about 3 years, so these methods were available and might well have been referred to by the developers.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, there are a few stat-generation methods in *Players Options: Skills and Powers* (1995) that do use points and thus allow one-for-one adjustments to stats. It's not starting from a die roll, though, so a little different. (Except for the one that has you roll on a table to see how many points you even have, which is a bit like rolling 3d6 down the line and then just reassigning pips at will.) I don't know the timeline for BG, but these alternate types of methods were surely discussed in *Dragon* articles well before their printing in *S&P*.

Comment: @nitsua60 ah, good catch. BGI was released in 1998, so S&P predates it by a few years.